# Is there anyway to set "no backreference" as default in php regex?

Tags: php, regex, web

I am aware that the regex engine moves significantly faster without having to keep track of backreferences. I am also aware that I can add a `?:` at the start of the inside of the brackets to prevent the regex engine from performing a backreference.

However is there anyway I can invert the behavior such that non-matching becomes the default behavior ?(rather like the `U` flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

PHP uses the PCRE library for parsing regular expressions.

PCRE uses an NFA-based parser which keeps track of backreferences.  What you are describing is a DFA-based parser or a Thompson NFA.

I'm not a PHP developer, but the PCRE library does indeed come with a "DFA mode."  Most Linux distros will come equipped with "pcretest."  If you don't have it, it comes with the PCRE library.

In the CLI:

```
$ pcretest
  re> /(foo)\1/
data> foofoo
  0: foofoo
  1: foo
```

Now if we run this with the "-dfa" flag:

```
$ pcretest -dfa
  re> /(foo)\1/
data> foofoo
Error -16
```

You may also want to look into "possessive quantifiers" to prevent backtracking.

Comment: @RogerP: you should have stuck with the short answer only.

Comment: @salathe I mean why stick with the short answer?

Comment: Because that is the answer, the rest is needless fluff. Why no interested?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use PHP PECL RE2 http://pecl.php.net/package/re2